# How to implement shell "ls -v" in java

Tags: java, shell, groovy

For example, I run `ls -v /tmp/chk` get:

```
ar1  ar20  ar100  pr1  pr20  pr100
```

but when I use following groovy code:

```
new File("/tmp/chk").listFiles().sort().each {
    println it.name
}
```

the result is:

```
ar1
ar100
ar20
pr1
pr100
pr20
```

How to implement `ls -v` algorithm to get same order in java or groovy

Comment: remove the `sort()` in `Groovy` code

Comment: Use [natural order](https://github.com/paour/natorder) comparator, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code implement alphanumeric sort

```
public class NaturalOrderComparator implements Comparator {
    int compareRight(String a, String b) {
        int bias = 0;
        int ia = 0;
        int ib = 0;

        // The longest run of digits wins. That aside, the greatest
        // value wins, but we can't know that it will until we've scanned
        // both numbers to know that they have the same magnitude, so we
        // remember it in BIAS.
        for (; ; ia++, ib++) {
            char ca = charAt(a, ia);
            char cb = charAt(b, ib);

            if (!Character.isDigit(ca) && !Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                return bias;
            } else if (!Character.isDigit(ca)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                return +1;
            } else if (ca < cb) {
                if (bias == 0) {
                    bias = -1;
                }
            } else if (ca > cb) {
                if (bias == 0)
                    bias = +1;
            } else if (ca == 0 && cb == 0) {
                return bias;
            }
        }
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String a = o1.toString();
        String b = o2.toString();

        int ia = 0, ib = 0;
        int nza = 0, nzb = 0;
        char ca, cb;
        int result;

        while (true) {
            // only count the number of zeroes leading the last number compared
            nza = nzb = 0;

            ca = charAt(a, ia);
            cb = charAt(b, ib);

            // skip over leading spaces or zeros
            while (Character.isSpaceChar(ca) || ca == '0') {
                if (ca == '0') {
                    nza++;
                } else {
                    // only count consecutive zeroes
                    nza = 0;
                }

                ca = charAt(a, ++ia);
            }

            while (Character.isSpaceChar(cb) || cb == '0') {
                if (cb == '0') {
                    nzb++;
                } else {
                    // only count consecutive zeroes
                    nzb = 0;
                }

                cb = charAt(b, ++ib);
            }

            // process run of digits
            if (Character.isDigit(ca) && Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                if ((result = compareRight(a.substring(ia), b.substring(ib))) != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            if (ca == 0 && cb == 0) {
                // The strings compare the same. Perhaps the caller
                // will want to call strcmp to break the tie.
                return nza - nzb;
            }

            if (ca < cb) {
                return -1;
            } else if (ca > cb) {
                return +1;
            }

            ++ia;
            ++ib;
        }
    }

    static char charAt(String s, int i) {
        if (i >= s.length()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return s.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = new String[]{"1-2", "1-02", "1-20", "10-20", "fred", "jane", "pic01",
                "pic2", "pic02", "pic02a", "pic3", "pic4", "pic 4 else", "pic 5", "pic05", "pic 5",
                "pic 5 something", "pic 6", "pic   7", "pic100", "pic100a", "pic120", "pic121",
                "pic02000", "tom", "x2-g8", "x2-y7", "x2-y08", "x8-y8"};

        List orig = Arrays.asList(strings);

        System.out.println("Original: " + orig);

        List scrambled = Arrays.asList(strings);
        Collections.shuffle(scrambled);

        System.out.println("Scrambled: " + scrambled);

        Collections.sort(scrambled, new NaturalOrderComparator());

        System.out.println("Sorted: " + scrambled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at Process Builder. It is really built for this kind of thing.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "", "ls -v");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String readline;
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    files.add(readline);
}
```

Comment: I hope use java implement this algorithm

Comment: For sure @asullaherc

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, When I run `ls -v` in a directory with that content, I get:

```
ar1    ar100  ar20   pr1    pr100  pr20
```

So I guess YMMV. However, if you are asking to have the non-numeric portions of the filenames sort *lexicographically*, and to have the numeric portions of the filenames sort *numerically*, you could try something like this:

```
def parseWord(String word) {
    def (isLex, list, current) = [true, [], '']
    word.each { c ->
        if (c in ('0'..'9') != isLex) {
            current += c
        } else {
            list << (isLex ? current : (current as int))
            isLex = !isLex
            current = c as String
        }
    }
    list << (isLex ? current : (current as int))
}

new File("/tmp/chk").listFiles().sort{ a, b ->
    def aa = parseWord(a.name)
    def bb = parseWord(b.name)
    ([aa, bb].transpose().findResult { it[0]<=>it[1] ?: null }) ?: 0
}.each {
    println it.name
}
```

Using that groovy script on at directory with your file content, I get the following results:

```
ar1
ar20
ar100
pr1
pr20
pr100
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this solution, @asullaherc ? Does it do what you want it to?